# Find DOMCompleteTime and LoadTime using JS (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, web-performance

How do you get the `DomContentLoaded` and the `Load` timings using [the Navigation Timing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/hh673552(v=vs.85)), or any other method?

The benchmark is reaching as close to the values shown below (in the console in the Network Tab of Firefox)

[image: Firefox Network Tab Timings]

I have already tried using

`window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart` 
for DOMContentLoaded, and

`window.performance.timing.loadEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart` for Load Time,

but they don't measure the timings properly.

Edit : As I found out (and have answered below), this is a Firefox specific issue - Chrome gives a margin of error of around ~5-10 ms, which is reasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, this is a Firefox specific issue.
When I run

1. `window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart` for `domLoadTime`, and
2. `window.performance.timing.loadEventEnd - window.performance.timing.navigationStart` for `loadTime`

on Chrome, I get a difference of ~5-10 ms from the reported time on the console.

On Firefox, the difference is around ~50-80 ms.

[This](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lgmnmdkkghdeagbghognjbjijpnckcid) great Chrome extension helped me in debugging the issue.